The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, Terraform
Here is my code
resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "duplicate_private_endpoint_dns_a_record_for_prod" {
  count               = var.resource_name != "" && strcontains(var.resource_name, "prod") ? 1 : 0 
  provider            = azurerm.saas-sharednonprod
  name                = var.resource_name
  zone_name           = var.private_dns_zone
  resource_group_name = var.dns_zone_resource_group_name
  ttl                 = 10
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.private_endpoint.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
  tags                = var.tags
}

It fails with the following error message
Error: Invalid count argument
│
│   on ../private_end_point/main.tf line 43, in resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "duplicate_private_endpoint_dns_a_record_for_prod":
│   43:   count               = var.resource_name != "" && strcontains(var.resource_name, "prod") ? 1 : 0
│
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
│ until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be
│ created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only
│ the resources that the count depends on.

I cannot really split the run into two stages so -target argument is not an option. I was trying to set resource name default to empty string but it didn't help.
variable "resource_name" {
  default = ""
}

EDIT 1
I am using Terraform 1.5.7 version
EDIT 2
The parent module that makes the call is
module "private_end_point" {
  source                         = "../private_end_point"
  private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.key-vault.id
  private_dns_zone               = "privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net"
  resource_name                  = azurerm_key_vault.key-vault.name
  location                       = var.location
  resource_group_name            = var.kv-rsg-name
  private_endpoint_subnet_id     = var.private_endpoint_subnet_id
  subresource_names              = ["vault"]
  dns_zone_resource_group_name   = var.dns_zone_resource_group_name
  providers = {
    azurerm.saas-sharednonprod = azurerm.saas-sharednonprod
    azurerm.saas-shared        = azurerm.saas-shared
  }
}


I couldn't reproduce your issue using a null_resource with count = var.resource_name != "" && strcontains(var.resource_name, "prod") ? 1 : 0. Which version of Terraform are you using? I'm using v1.9.8

have to tried using foreach instead of count @AlexeyAuslender

Based on the comments below the answer, if I got it right, you are passing the value for the resource_name variable by providing an output from another module, right? So resource_name = module.app_service.app_service_name will not work. That's why terraform is complaining. You might try moving the logic for the variable value to the local variables in the root module. So something like locals { resource_name =  strcontains(module.app_service.app_service_name, "prod") }. Then, in the module call you can try using resource_name = local.resource_name. Not sure if that will work.

@MarkoE your proposition didn't work, exporting module.app_service.app_service_name into local on parent level and passing it as a parameter into subordinate module still causes the same error.

Did you try referring locals after using foreach? so that local variable to determine whether the DNS A record should be created.@AlexeyAuslender

Hi @VinayB yes I did, it didn't help. For now my solution was to elevate the nested azurerm_private_dns_a_record resource to the same level as of module "private_end_point", not ideal but works

I think the typical solutions to this error can't work here because the condition is based on the actual value of var.resource_name, and so if that isn't known then there's nothing Terraform can do to guess whether this is production or not. Would you be open to the idea of passing the environment name as a separate input variable, rather than overloading the resource name to also imply the environment? I think that will make your life considerably easier because then the known-ness of the resource name will be independent of the known-ness of the environment name.


Using foreach instead of Count in the condition where the resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply while using terraform.

Here your requirement to create a DNS a record only when the name matches or included PROD key word can't be achieved using count because while using count terraform wont conclude the resources that it should create the resources that should be created.
Where are in case of foreach we need define the criteria variable. If this parameter matches, then the resource provision will take place.
My updated configuration using foreach for single resource case
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "dns_zone" {
  name                = "privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}


resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
  name                = "private-endpoint-vksb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "private-endpoint-psc-example"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.storage.id
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }
}


resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "duplicate_private_endpoint_dns_a_record_for_prod" {
  for_each = { for k, v in { prod = var.resource_name } : k => v if var.resource_name != "" && strcontains(var.resource_name, "prod") }

  provider            = azurerm.saas-sharednonprod # Refers to the aliased provider
  name                = each.value
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.dns_zone.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  ttl                 = 10
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.private_endpoint.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
}


variable "resource_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource to be created. It should include 'prod' to create the DNS A Record."
  default     = "prod-vksb"
}

Deployment:


If we need do not enter any keyword that matches the requirement lets say "dev-vksb" like prod in this case, it won't create the record and show as no changes make

Only drawback with the approach is we need specify the variable  list as string also by including the keyword if you want to create.
If you have more than one variable to create then modify the foreach condition as mentioned below
 for_each = {
    for name in var.resource_names : name => name if contains(name, "prod")
  }

And the variable input be a list of inputs that are predefined.
variable "resource_names" { 
description = "A list of resource names. DNS A Records will be created for those containing 'prod'."
type = list(string) 
default = ["prod-vksb", "dev-vksb", "test-vksb", "prod-test"....]  }

Refer:
azurerm_private_dns_a_record | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry

I've tried this code and I am getting the same error
Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on ../private_end_point/main.tf line 44, in resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "duplicate_private_endpoint_dns_a_record_for_prod":
│   44:   for_each            = { for k, v in { prod = var.resource_name } : k => v if var.resource_name != "" && strcontains(var.resource_name, "prod") }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.resource_name is a string, known only after apply
│
│ The "for_each" map includes keys derived from resource attributes that
│ cannot be determined until apply

may i know know how you passing the input variable  we need to define the value in variables or tfvars @AlexeyAuslender

private_end_point is a module and it gets resource_name variable as following
resource_name  = module.app_service.app_service_name

will you try to update for_each = var.resource_name != "" && strcontains(var.resource_name, "prod") ? { prod = var.resource_name } : {} and try again @AlexeyAuslender

44:   for_each = var.resource_name != "" && strcontains(var.resource_name, "prod") ? { prod = var.resource_name } : {}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.resource_name is a string, known only after apply

Can youn please update the code with some more info so that I will be able to find the pain point of how you refering the resource name @AlexeyAuslender
